# How to make jetbrains pycharm auto format code on paste

Tags: pycharm, webstorm

When I used webstorm and I pasted a bit of code from somewhere else it would do the formatting for me. But with pycharm 3, it is not happening anymore and I have to manually indent the code etc.

I want to get that feature back. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: **1)** Select your code fragment and `Code | Reformat Code...` or `Code | Auto-Indent Lines` ? **2)** Check what you have at `Settings | Editor | Smart Keys | Reformat on paste`  **P.S.** These are just general suggestions, since I'm not a PyCharm user.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Edit** to keep up to date:

The option `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Smart indent pasted lines` will be of interest (Pycharm 2016.3).

Things are always evolving, as a general (and faster) practice, I would recommend to start typing `smart indent` as soon as the settings window appear. Menus will narrow down to help find where the option sits.

Or even more fancy, `Ctrl + Shift + A` directly from the editor (*search everywhere*) can bring you to it.

Comment: thank you very much. Just so others know, there are 4 additional sub-options, "None" will leave the formatting in tact as you paste.

Comment: PyCharm 5 has it under `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Reformat  on Paste`, fyi.

Answer (score 10):

Short cut for auto formatting: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>